# Why are my animate.css animations working in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

My animations are not working in Firefox; they fade-in but do not slide-in from the outside like they do in Chrome.
I am using the [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) library to give animation.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qvq8z4zo/)

```css
h2{
   text-align:center;
}
span {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 3s !important;
     -moz-animation-duration: 3s !important;
     -o-animation-duration: 3s !important;
     animation-duration: 3s !important;
}
.dly {
     -webkit-animation-delay: 2s !important;
     -moz-animation-delay: 2s !important;
     -o-animation-delay: 2s !important;
     animation-delay: 2s !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2>
        <span class="animated  fadeInLeftBig">A</span>
        <span class="dly animated  bounceInDown"> B</span>
        <span class="animated  fadeInRightBig"> C</span>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Why are they working in Chrome, but not in Firefox? How can I make them work in Firefox?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? It works for me in Firefox 37

Comment: check animation in chrome and than check in firefox totally different.

Comment: Or explain what you mean by "doesn't work", @Rock. If you want others to help you, you can't expect them to do the work of debugging the problem for you. :-)

Comment: @TylerH  animation works fine in chrome. but not working in my firefox. I am using  firefox 37.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to `span`. It is because css `transforms` [are not supposed to work](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#terminology) on `inline` elements. For some reason it works in Webkit though.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qvq8z4zo/1/)

Its a [known issue](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/265) and has been dicussed @ animate.css github

Comment: You might also want to add `.container {overflow: hidden;}` to remove the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @TylerH sure :) but the issue was bug in ff.

Comment: Actually the bug is non-spec behavior in Chrome; Firefox works as it's supposed to ;-)